# Kafka Topic retention.ms not working when used in Spark Streaming context

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am running a Spark Streaming job (means that data keeps getting pushed to a kafka topic and read by Spark consumer continuously). My Kafka topic for Input data has a retention time set to 60000 (1 Min). However, Input Topic doesn't clear messages after 1 minute. It takes approx 1:26 mins to clear if no new data got added to the topic.

If I add data continously for two mintues, I would expect half of old data to be cleared because of retention.ms set to 1 min. But I just see double data.

Has anyone seen similar pattern. How can I resolve this? Would you need more details?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the property [log.retention.check.interval.ms](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#configuration) to set *the frequency in milliseconds that the log cleaner checks whether any log is eligible for deletion*.